# How to amend IRS form 8606?

Tags: united-states, ira, form-8606

How can I amend an [IRS tax form 8606](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8606.pdf) (Nondeductible IRAs)?  The form has a signature line, allowing it to be filed by itself, but I already filed one for the year in question and now need to amend it to make a correction. How can I do this? Do I just file another form 8606, or must I do a 1040-X? Do I also send this amended form 8606 to my state of California? Note that my 1040 remains unchanged with the update to the form 8606.

Comment: If you amend the form and any of the lines taken to 1040 change - you have to file 1040X. In this case you also have to send the form to Cali (They require copies of anything that triggered the amendment). However I have no idea if you can change a 8606 after it has been submitted, so not posting it as an answer...

Comment: My 1040 is unchanged with the amendment.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm in this boat for a few years, and the 8606 doesn't change my 1040, so I'm not sure whether to include the unchanged 1040X or just the revised (or not included) 8606.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Instructions for Form 8606](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8606.pdf):

> **Amending Form 8606**
>
> After you file your return, you can change a nondeductible contribution to a traditional IRA to a deductible
> contribution or vice versa. You also may be able to make a
> recharacterization (see page 3). If necessary, complete a new Form
> 8606 showing the revised information and file it with Form 1040X,
> Amended U.S. Individual Income Tax Return